# Ruby-Git gets wrong tag info

Tags: ruby, git, github

using ruby-git, a private repo cloned from github located at PATH_TO_REPO_NAME

```
g = Git.open("PATH_TO_REPO_NAME")
tag="us_prod"
puts g.tag(tag)
```

result is not what appears under https://github.com/gtforge/REPO_NAME/tags

Comment: Did you mean `puts g.tag(tag)` for the last line?

Answer (score 0):

error eventually was that while I pulled from the repo, I didnt fetch the tags separately, which is because I did not know that was required. false alarm.